# How to prove the statement "If $A^4=I_n$, then $\det A=1$" if it is true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, determinant

Statement: If $A^4=I_n$, then $\det A = 1$.

We know that if $\det A = 1$, it is considered to be unimodular.
Specifically, if the determinant of a matrix is $0$, the matrix is said to be singular, and if the determinant is $1$, the matrix is said to be unimodular.

Now, how can I prove the given statement above if it is true or false using the logic of $\det A = 1$? I am a little bit confused about how I can pull off the proof for the statement to be either true or false.

Comment: If $A=(-1)$, then $A^4=(1)=I$ but $\det(A)=-1$. What we can prove is that $\det(A)$ will be a solution of $x^4=1$, since $1=\det(I)=\det(A^4)=\det(A)^4$. There are other solutions of this equation besides $x=1$. Other solutions are $x=-1$, $x=i$ and $x=-i$.

Comment: @user85667 Actually $\det(-I)=\pm1$, depending on the dimension...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Irrelevant. No $\det(-I)$ around.

Comment: @user85667 Then what matrix did you mean when you wrote $A=(-1)$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich There is a $1=\{\{\}\}$ there, with a minus in front, inside a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: there is no {{}} visible. in any case, what does 1={{}} mean? (And is the result not the negative of a 1x1 identity?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I understood $(-1)$ to mean the $1\times 1$ matrix whose unique entry is $-1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thx. But that's how I understood it as well, until user#n said it was _not_ $-I$. (As in "Then what matrix did you mean when you wrote $A=(-1)$?".)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It's not *just* $-I$; it's $-I$ in the special case where the dimension of the matrix is $1\times 1$. (And in that special case, the determinant is indeed $-1$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass True. When I said that's how I read it as well, actually that's how I eventually read it. At first it looked like $(-I)$...)

Comment: Since the equation can have other solutions besides x = 1, then the statement above is true or false? @user85667

Comment: @RalphHenry Yes, the statement is false, because there are other possibilities.

Comment: @user85667 ok, will take note of that, thank you very much!!! Thank you also for the good clarification discussion with David C.Ullrich and Andreas Blass